# Reading xml files in to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, xml

I have a folder with several other folders. These folders all contain xml files

I have written code to extract the data into a df. Can i write in such a way that i specify all the file directories in my code and once the file is run it extracts the xml from all the folders?

```
import nltk
import os
import pandas as pd
from lxml import etree

dir = 'directory' 

speakers_data = [ ]


# Define namespaces

ns = {
'tb': 'http://www.talkbank.org/ns/talkbank',
'xsi': 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'
}

for name in os.listdir(dir:
if name.endswith('.xml'):
file_path = os.path.join(dir, name)

        tree = etree.parse(file_path)
        
        folder_name = os.path.basename(os.path.dirname(file_path))
    
        speakers = []
        for participant in tree.xpath("//tb:Participants/tb:participant", namespaces=ns):
            speaker_info = {
                'speaker_name': participant.get('name'),
                'role': participant.get('role'),
                'age': participant.get('age'),
                'sex': participant.get('sex')
            }
            speakers_info.append(speakers)
        
        df_speakers = pd.DataFrame(speakers)
        speakers_data.append(df_speakers)

speakers_data = pd.concat(speakers_data, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Your XML looks pretty flat that you may consider [**`read_xml`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_xml.html): `df_speakers = pd.read_xml(file_path, "//tb:Participants/tb:participant", namespaces=ns)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `os.walk()` to search all .xml in the directory or subdirectories, too (with topdown=True):

```
import os

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(".", topdown=False):
   for name in files:
       if name.endswith('.xml'):
           # do something ...
          print(os.path.join(root, name))
```